# Lambda function does not return all rows from MySQL

Tags: python, lambda, unicode

I am trying to make a simple AWS Lambda function to get few rows from Amazon RDS(MySQL db) and return it in the json format.

If I try to append the object instance then I get error that object of type XXX is not json serializable. If I do something like below then I get only latest entry from the db. (This is unlike to what shown in https://hackersandslackers.com/create-a-rest-api-endpoint-using-aws-lambda/).

```
def save_events(event):
    result = []
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host,user=name,passwd=password,db=db_name,connect_timeout=5)
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from tblEmployees")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            employee = Employee(row)
            data['Id'] = employee.id
            data['Name']= employee.name
            result.append(data)
    return result

def main(event, context):
    data = save_events(event)
    return {
        "StatusCode":200,
        "Employee": data
    }
```

I understand that the contend of variable 'data' changes runtime and it affects on result.append(). I've 4 entries in table tblEmployees. The output of above gets 4 entries in the result but all the four entries are same (and equal to the latest record in the db).
The json.dumps() didn't work as the data is in the unicode format. I've already tried .toJSON() and byteify() and it didn't work.
Any help ?

Comment: It looks like you are over-writing the values in `data` on each iteration of the for loop.  You need to create a new dict for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes, you are so right. I'd declared data={} in the function (but not inside the loop). I moved the definition inside the loop and it worked. ! Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-create the data to avoid overriding old values:

```py
for row in rows:
    employee = Employee(row)
    data = new Dict(Id=employee.id, Name=employee.name)
    result.append(data)
```